# How to know from which domain I am getting mails from myself?

Tags: email, php, webserver, domain

I am getting mail from myself, I know it is getting sent through php or through any other server side script. But I want to know from which domain I am getting those mails from myself. I am a php developer so I can tell that those messages are from some script but how to find the domain/website from which it is getting sent. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

**Solution to this:** (my reputation is below 10 so i cannot post answer to my own question so posting here :) )

You may not actually find out the exact sender of the mail but atleast you can get some hint about the sender. As if you are a developer and forgot to remove the test mail id from the websites mail script (as me :P) then at that time this will help you...

What I did is:

1) Opened the mail and clicked the small dropdown beside the reply button which is on the right side of the message.
2) under that dropdown chose the "show original" option.
3) The mail header opened in a new window. In that find the text something like this:

```
Received: from mout.per****.net (mout.per****.net. [74.xx8.4.xxx])
```

4) Copy that Ip and using any whois utility and find that IP.
5) By doing this you will get the hosting providers name under "NetName" head.

This helped me finding which website's php script was sending mail to myself. Hope this will also help you...!

Comment: Can't you check the headers which contains information on every server that touched the email?

Comment: I checked all that but found nothing useful I want the domain address who is sending me these mails...

Comment: The header should have this information at the very least it will indicate the ip address.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to tell from the message headers.  Depending on which email client you are using, there are different ways to view these headers.

The header information you are looking for is the originating IP or domain fields.

[This article](http://lifehacker.com/how-can-i-find-out-where-an-email-really-came-from-1190061668) describes an extended method of using the emails header information to trace where the message is coming from.  IT focuses specifically on GMail as a destination, but the principals hold up nicely

Comment: Hi @Fazer87 thanks for your reply but I found that using whois utility. That was my fault actually, while fixing one site's issue i forgot to change the mail id to theirs that was causing the issue.